# Saving and retrieving values with SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I want to save two values using shared preferences and get those values in other classes. Can any one please give me information about how to set shared preferences and getting value from shared preferences.

I am using following code:

```
SharedPreferences settings =  
        getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 

    SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = gameSettings.edit();  
    prefEditor.putString("KEY", "e6c77c29021c9b3bd55aa0e9b7687ad9");  
    prefEditor.putString("SECRET", "ca85fa3fe86edaf2");
    prefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: dealing with shared preference is quite simple and very easy to understand, here is the link for the beginner http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: what you've done here is exactly how you save values

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SharedPreferences button1; 
String name1="",name2="";
button1=this.getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        name1=button1.getString("KEY", "");
        name2=button1.getString("SECRET", "");



 SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = button1.edit();  
     prefEditor.putString("KEY","e6c77c29021c9b3bd55aa0e9b7687ad9");  
     prefEditor.putString("SECRET", "ca85fa3fe86edaf2");
     prefEditor.commit();
```

now stored two values.

Comment: Don't store passwords, or any key as `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. If you realkly have to store them, use: `MODE_PRIVATE `

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("prefEditor ", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String key = myPrefs.getString(KEY, "nothing");
String secret = myPrefs.getString(SECRET, "nothing");

you can retrieve the values, using the getString method by passing the Key and a default value.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

my problem was how to retrieve these stored values in another file. it was cleared 
 my code is

```
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);


      String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key", "");
      String secret = sharedPreferences.getString("secret", "");
```

Thanks .